# Live search through object

Tags: javascript

I have a function that live searches through a JavaScript object and it works well other than I'm having trouble with part of the functionality.

The function displays the results just fine but I can't seem to get the results to clear once the user types in something that doesn't match.

The `searchData` object is full of a bunch of information but right now I'm just trying to search through the ids.

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function () {
    let searchField = $(this).val();

    if (searchField === "") {
        $("#search .search-results").remove();
        return;
    }

    let regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    let output = "";

    $.each(searchData, function (key, val) {
        if (val.id.search(regex) != -1) {
            output +=
                "<p class='search-results'>" + val.id + "</p>";

            $("#search .search-results").remove();
            $("#search").append(output);
        }
    });
});
```

So now if the user types 328 it'll show them the corresponding id with 328 but if they type 3289 it still shows that id even though there isn't one that relates to that number.

I tried adding an else clause in the search that would empty the results but that resulted in nothing being appended even with a valid search.

Comment: you may do $("#search").html("") before the $.each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line

```
 $("#search .search-results").remove();
```

is only called IF you find something, or the search bar is empty.

so when you search for 3289, nothing shows up and the list isn't cleared. Also, if you have more than one match, only the last one will be added

a quick fix I'd suggest is to call `[...].remove()` anyways before launching the search ; and NOT inside the $each callback :

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function () {
    let searchField = $(this).val();

    //we call this one anyways
    $("#search .search-results").remove();
    if (searchField === "") {
        return;
    }

    let regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    let output = "";

    $.each(searchData, function (key, val) {
        if (val.id.search(regex) != -1) {
            output +=
                "<p class='search-results'>" + val.id + "</p>";

            //and we remove this one
            //$("#search .search-results").remove();
            $("#search").append(output);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: *only the last one will be added* because of... ? and wheres the solution?

Comment: I added that line just to clear the results everytime because they were being appended onto the old results.

Currently if I search for 3289 I see the result for 328.

Comment: I followed your advice from the revision and it works as expected. Thank you for your help!

Comment: no problem. To be fair, Jonas's comment works just as well :)